# how to escape double quotes with formatting?

Tags: python, json

i have a csv with columns,

```
Column_one | Column_two

 1         | apple
 2         | orange
...
```

```
import csv
import json

rows=[]
dataRow = {}
with open('input.csv', mode='r') as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        rows.append('"{0}":"{1}"'.format(row["Column_one"], row["Column_two"]))
    with open('output.json', 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write(json.dumps(rows))
```

I am formatting the output so that i can get output file as such

```
{"1" : "apple"}
{"2" : "orange"}
```

but i get results below  , i tried escaping the double quotes with add backlash in front of double quotes, but that just gives me double backlash infront of quotes

```
{\"1\": \"apple:\"}, 
{\"2\" : \"orange\"}
```

Comment: @khelwood - the code i posted is exactly how i'm using it.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you're basically writing something that is supposed to look like JSON, and then using `json.dumps`, which encodes it as JSON again. If you want to write `{"1":"apple"}` with `json.dumps`, then you need to give it a dictionary `{"1":"apple"}`, not a string `'"1":"apple"'`.

Comment: Worth pointing out that your file should also have `[]` since you are dumping a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *individual objects* on each line, then you cannot dump an entire list.

Separate your concerns - parse the file into dict rows, then write a new one.

```
import csv
def csv2dict(filename):
  with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    h1, h2 = reader.fieldnames[:2]
    for r in reader:
      yield {r[h1]:r[h2]}
      # Or to get all column headers to their values
      # yield {f:r[f] for f in reader.fieldnames}

import json
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
  for d in csv2dict('input.csv'):
    json.dump(d, f)
    f.write('\n')
```

Outputs

```
{"1": "apple"}
{"2": "orange"}
```

Note: You don't really need the DictReader; a regular `csv.Reader` has index access to the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this

```
import csv
import json

rows=[]
dataRow = {}
with open('input.csv', mode='r') as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        rows.append(dict(row["Column_one"]: row["Column_two"]))
    with open('output.json', 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write(json.dumps(rows, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are manually creating a string that looks like JSON, and then encoding it again with `json.dumps`, so you get a JSONified version of a JSON string.

You can write JSON manually if you want:

```
>>> print('{{"{}":"{}"}}'.format('1', 'apple'))
{"1":"apple"}
```

or (preferably) you can using the json module to encode a dictionary as JSON:

```
>>> print(json.dumps({'1':'apple'}))
{"1": "apple"}
```

But if you do both, you get a JSON representation of an already JSONified string, which looks like this:

```
>>> print(json.dumps('{{"{}":"{}"}}'.format('1', 'apple')))
"{\"1\":\"apple\"}"
```